# Oracle SQL - Retrieve the highest occurrence of a value grouped to another value

Tags: sql, oracle

First, I am using ORACLE SQL. I am working with a table that has two simple columns: NBHD and MODEL. What I need to do is first count the # of times each MODEL is used per NBHD. Then I need to take only the MODEL with the highest count per NBHD. I've been able to get a count of the # of times the MODEL is used per NBHD but I am stuck there.

First, here's the code to create a temp table that should be representative of the data I'm using.

```
create table temp_ctest (NBHD VARCHAR(2), MODEL VARCHAR(2));

insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'D');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('2', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('3', 'B');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('4', 'A');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'D');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('2', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('3', 'B');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('4', 'A');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'D');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('2', 'D');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('3', 'D');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('4', 'D');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'A');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('2', 'A');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('3', 'A');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('3', 'A');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('3', 'A');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('3', 'A');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('1', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('4', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('4', 'C');
insert into temp_ctest (NBHD, MODEL) VALUES ('4', 'C');
```

Here is the code I've already used to retrieve the count for the # of times each MODEL is used per NBHD.

```
select nbhd, model, count(model) modelcount 
from temp_ctest
group by nbhd, model 
order by nbhd, modelcount desc;
```

This retrieved the following list:

https://snipboard.io/UZ1x5L.jpg

I've tried using over (partition by) but I'm still fairly new to SQL and can't figure it out.

The results I'm hoping to achieve is a subset of the list above. I just want the highest occurring model per NBHD. For the given set I'd like to see the following result:

https://snipboard.io/HayLoZ.jpg

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: what if there are two models that have the highest count?

Comment: Please don't put links of images or code. Provide your code and expected result as formatted text.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit sorry about that, I'll make to do it appropriately next time!

Comment: @Boneist If this is the case, I would want to display both

Comment: You can edit your question and replace the links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select nbhd, model, modelcount 
from
(Select nbhd, model, modelcount, 
        dense_rank() over 
        (partition by nbhd order by modelcount desc) as rn 
from
(select nbhd, model, count(model) modelcount 
from temp_ctest
group by nbhd, model))
Where rn = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: the `row_number()` should be `dense_rank()` as the OP wants to keep all rows that have the highest count.

Comment: @boneist, yes actually OP gave that comment after I have given the answer. But Thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix window functions with aggregation:

```
select nbhd, model, modelcount
from (select nbhd, model, count(*) as modelcount,
             rank() over (partition by nbhd order by count(*) desc) as seqnm
      from temp_ctest
      group by nbhd, model 
     ) nm
where seqnum = 1
order by nbhd;
```